# Form with dynamic number of texboxes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider the following model and controller:

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Email Address is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("EmailAddress")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

[HandleError]
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Simple()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Simple(SimpleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // handling code here
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

... and the relevant section in the matching view:

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "The form submitted is not valid.") %>
    <div> 
        <fieldset>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

What would be the best way to modify the model, view and controller to support a dynamic number of email addresses defined by the controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on an article by [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) I was able to find the elegant solution I was looking for:

First of all, the model needs to be modified as follows:

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string Value { get; set; }        
}
```

The controller method handling the GET method needs to prepopulate the model with as many entries as required:

```
[HandleError]
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Simple()
    {
        SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel
            {
                EmailAddresses =
                    new List<EmailAddress>
                        { 
                            // as many as required
                            new EmailAddress { Value = string.Empty }, 
                            new EmailAddress { Value = string.Empty },
                            new EmailAddress { Value = string.Empty }
                        }
            };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Simple(SimpleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // handling code here
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The view also needs to change:

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "The form submitted is not valid.") %>
    <div> 
        <fieldset>
            <% foreach (var item in Model.EmailAddresses)
                   Html.RenderPartial("SimpleRows", item);
             %>

            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

... and a new partial view needs to be created. Note that the view is strongly-type with the type of the collection item.

```
<% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("EmailAddresses")) { %>
<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Value)%>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Value)%>
</div>
<% }%>
```

The BeginCollectionItem is a Helper method created by Sanderson:

```
    public static class HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
{
    private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";

    public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
    {
        var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
        string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
        html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

        return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
    }

    public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
    {
        return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
    }

    private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
    {
        // We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,  
        // otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
        string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
        var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
        if (queue == null) {
            httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
            var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                    queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
        }
        return queue;
    }

    private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
        private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

        public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

            previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
        }
    }
}
```

... and that's it... when you post the form the model will be automatically populated and passed to the controller action handling the POST method.

Note that with this solution all the attributes including the validation work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("EmailAddress")]
    public List<string> EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

[HandleError]
public class SimpleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SimpleTest()
    {
        SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel();
        model.EmailAddress = new List<string>();
        model.EmailAddress.Add("email1");
        model.EmailAddress.Add("email2");
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SimpleTest(FormCollection formvalues)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // handling code here
        }
        SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel();
        model.EmailAddress = new List<string>();
        model.EmailAddress.Add("email1");
        model.EmailAddress.Add("email2");
        return View();
    }
}
```

... and the relevant section in the matching view:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <%{
          foreach (var i in Model.EmailAddress)
          { %>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model =>i)%>
        <br />
    </div>
    <%}
      }%>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

I don't think the validation will work though.

Comment: Problems with your solution:
- How would you define the EmailAddress class?
- How the controller can define how many textboxes are displayed?
- The m.EmailAddressess reference in the foreach is not valid.
- Your solution drops the label and the validation messages for the texboxes.

Comment: You can actually just use string instead of creating class for EmailAddress.  The controller will loop through the List and and will display x amount of text boxes given that there are x amount of item in the list.  I think my syntax is off on that foreach loop, it was meant to be pseudo code not an actual code.  Are you trying to use the view to edit or create?

Comment: @atbebtg: Can you please try your solution in Visual Studio first? There are many things in your orginal solution that won't work. Now answering your question: The view will be used to collect a variable number of NEW email address entered by the user.

Comment: @atbebtg: I noticed your changes. My comments:
- Ideally I would like to get the SimpleModel as parameter for the controller action instead of the FormCollection.
- Getting the validation working using the attributes is also a must have feature.

Comment: you may want to look into the following article to work with the simplemodel as the return value http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: @atbebtg: Thanks for your input but in the end your solution didn't satisfy all the requirements I was looking for.

Comment: What would happen if we want to add elements using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I also marked the answer by @JCallico as correct.

For any die-hard VB coders here's the extension method by Steve Sanderson in your favourite language:

```
 'from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236251/form-with-dynamic-number-of-texboxes-in-asp-net-mvc based on http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Web.Mvc
    Imports System.Web
    Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem
    Public Module HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
        Private Const IdsToReuseKey As String = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_"

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
        Public Function BeginCollectionItem(html As HtmlHelper, collectionName As String) As IDisposable
            Return BeginCollectionItem(html, collectionName, html.ViewContext.Writer)
        End Function

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
        Public Function BeginCollectionItem(html As HtmlHelper, collectionName As String, writer As TextWriter) As IDisposable
            Dim idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName)
            Dim itemIndex = If(idsToReuse.Count > 0, idsToReuse.Dequeue(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString())

            ' autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour
            ' whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the
            ' xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
            writer.WriteLine("<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}.index"" autocomplete=""off"" value=""{1}"" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex))

            Return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex))
        End Function

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
        Public Function BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html As HtmlHelper, htmlFieldPrefix As String) As IDisposable
            Return New HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix)
        End Function

        Private Function GetIdsToReuse(httpContext As HttpContextBase, collectionName As String) As Queue(Of String)
            ' We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,
            ' otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
            Dim key = IdsToReuseKey & collectionName
            Dim queue = DirectCast(httpContext.Items(key), Queue(Of String))
            If queue Is Nothing Then
                httpContext.Items(key) = InlineAssignHelper(queue, New Queue(Of String)())
                Dim previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request(collectionName & Convert.ToString(".index"))
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds) Then
                    For Each previouslyUsedId In previouslyUsedIds.Split(","c)
                        queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            Return queue
        End Function

        Friend Class HtmlFieldPrefixScope
            Implements IDisposable
            Friend ReadOnly TemplateInfo As TemplateInfo
            Friend ReadOnly PreviousHtmlFieldPrefix As String

            Public Sub New(templateInfo__1 As TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix As String)
                TemplateInfo = templateInfo__1

                PreviousHtmlFieldPrefix = TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
                TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix
            End Sub

            Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
                TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = PreviousHtmlFieldPrefix
            End Sub
        End Class
        Private Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

I am happily using this with [Value Injector](https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).